# 3-phase motor body earth

Tags: three-phase

A 3-phase 90 kW motor connected through VFD tripped due to over load. Frequency was set at 49 Hz. I lowered the frequency to 42 and the motor is running smoothly now. The current in phases were as follows

1. Red - 124 A
2. Yellow - 124 A
3. Blue - 126 A
4. Body Earth - 4 A

This is a new motor and why does the body earth cable carrying 4 A when it should be zero? Is it because of the current difference between phases?

Comment: "why does the body earth cable carrying 4A when it should be zero. Is it because of the current difference between phases?" Yes. But why are the phases carrying different current? I don't know. It could just be natural imbalances in the motor, and nothing to worry about. Or it could indicate a defect. Do you have a spec sheet for the motor?

Comment: I would first check to see if the 4A is real - measure red, yellow and blue at the same time.  That will tell you your ground fault current.

Comment: Could it be due to changing magnetic flux in the winding that induces current in body?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In case your grid is 3x400 V, the line current you measured is close to the rated current of a standard 90 kW motor. Check the motor plate current at your voltage net, this is the limit you have to look when you ajust the speed. The mechanical load will determine this point.

Regarding the current at ground cable, it is mainly caused from parasitic capacitances of cables and motor.
See schematics from here:
https://cache.industry.siemens.com/dl/files/185/83180185/att_1026522/v1/G130_G150_S120_S150_ext_config_man_0620_en-US.pdf

[image]
Also you can see in that document how to reduce this high frecuency interferences.
A 90 kW power drive should normally use a filter at the entry and symetrical screened cables to the motor.
Also, one of motor bearings (normally the smaller one, B-side) should be isolated, otherwise the life of bearings will be reduced because step voltage edges will generate bearings current.